# Can I run/debug files with babel-node in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, babeljs

I know there are Run/Debug configurations in WebStorm, but I don't know how to configure the context menu (when I right click in a file, it has Run... and Debug... in the menu, but I can't find where to configure this).

Answer (score 9):

Run configurations are created via `Run | Edit Configurations...` : press `+`, choose `Node.js`, in created configuration specify babel-node as Node Interpreter:

[image]

But note that debugging doesn't work well when using it. I'd strongly recommend using `-r @babel/register` Node.js parameter instead - see comments in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21949

Comment: `-r babel-register` is life saver

Comment: It's now @babel/register, so you'd use `-r @babel/register`. See https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register/.